# A question on the equation $^qx=2$

Tags: rational-numbers, tetration

Given the equation $$^qx=2$$ with $q\gt3$ where $^qx$ means the 'tetration' operation on $x$, my question is: is it possible to find a value for $q$ for which the solution $x$ of the equation is a rational number? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I forgot to put the condition $q\gt3$

Comment: @DanielFischer: I corrected the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound for your number is:
$b=1.476684337357869947089235585 \;\;\; b \uparrow \uparrow 3 = 2$

If you extend tetration to the real numbers, than any $b>\sqrt{2}$ and less than the answer I gave would have $b \uparrow \uparrow x = 2$ for some number x>=3 and less than infinity.  For example, I used Newton's method for these results.

$$b=1.47668433735787 \;\;\; b \uparrow \uparrow 3 = 2\;\; \text{upper bounds}$$
$$b=1.4584946676581 \;\; b \uparrow \uparrow 3.5=2$$
$$b=1.4466014324299 \;\;  b \uparrow \uparrow 4=2$$
$$b=1.4326948056602 \;\;  b \uparrow \uparrow 5=2$$

In the limit, if $b=\sqrt{2}$, then the limit as n goes to infinity,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2} \uparrow \uparrow n = 2$$

$$\text{if} \;b<\sqrt{2}, \;\; \text{then} \;\; \lim_{n \to \infty} b \uparrow \uparrow n < 2$$

Comment: I don't see how this connects to finding a rational solution. Also, how are you defining up-arrow notation for non-integer right-side operands?

Comment: The best extension for Tetration to the complex plane is Kneser's construction, which is what I used.  See the tetration forum: http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=486  For every $\sqrt{2}<b<\approx 1.476684337357$ there is one exact tetration height, $h>=3$, for which $b \uparrow \uparrow h = 2$